# Use upper-level directory in autotools projects

Tags: autotools

I have a repository of projects with following structure:

```
repo/
  configure.ac
  Makefile.am
  project1/
    configure.ac
    Makefile.am
    [sources]
  project2/
    configure.ac
    Makefile.am
    [sources]
  project3/
    configure.ac
    Makefile.am
    [sources]
```

And now I need to add directory (lets say `common_logic/`) into `repo/` and modify somehow `project1` and `project2` to use sources from `common_logic`.

One of the solutions that I can see is to
copy `../common_logic/` after `./configure` (or before any rule in Makefile) executed in `project1/` and add in Makefile.am following lines:

```
project1_la_CFLAGS += -I./common_logic

project1_la_SOURCES += ./common_logic/foo.h ./common_logic/foo.c
```

In this case neither `make` nor `make dist` are broken. However it is looks like a crutch to me.

Anyway, could you please tell me how should `project1` and `project2` be modified to use the newely created folder? Or point another solution?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is best to build a convenience library from `common_logic`:

```
noinst_LTLIBRARIES = libcommonlogic.la
libcommonlogic_la_SOURCES = foo.c foo.h
```

Then, in `project1`'s `Makefile.am`:

```
project1_la_LIBADD = ../common_logic/libcommonlogic.la
```

Comment: This is solution for _in-place_ build. But `make dist` would be broken, correct?

Comment: Not correct; `make dist` will work because `libcommonlogic.la` will be built in `$(top_builddir)/common_logic/`, and the `project1.la` build will have a working directory of `$(top_builddir)/project1`. So the paths will remain the same relative to one another.

Comment: But if you don't believe me, then just try it out - I could be wrong ;-)

Comment: Well, `make dist` is broken as I expect. Either me or you did not understand each other.
http://pastebin.com/UP9gFP1w

Comment: I think we don't understand each other then ;-) I see nothing broken about that; `make dist` worked and you got a tarball, no?

Comment: As you can see, neither `pdb.cpp` nor `pdb.h` are presented in tarball. Hence build from this tarball (e.g. rpmbuild) will be broken.

Comment: Then something else is going wrong in your makefile. Any files declared in one of Automake's special `_SOURCES` variables should be in the tarball, no exceptions. Can you post more of your makefile?

Comment: Can you post the toplevel and `libplugindriver` makefiles?

Comment: I notice you didn't put `common_logic` into `SUBDIRS`?

Comment: This did not changed anything. And, IMO, it shouldn't.